# best way to reference an object before it is assigned?

Tags: c#, .net

for me coding is a lot about clarity and overview. Therefore i would love to call objects that aren't already assigned in the constructor of a class. Sounds like an stupid idea so here an example (might be stupid anyway):

```
// this doesn't work but looks clear
SomeClass a = new SomeClass(b, c);
SomeClass b = new SomeClass(a, c);
SomeClass c = new SomeClass(a, b);


// this functions but has bad overview:
SomeClass a = new SomeClass(null, null);
SomeClass b = new SomeClass(a, null);
SomeClass c = new SomeClass(a, b);
a.first = b;
a.snd = c;
b.snd = c;
```

Is there any nicer way to the one on the bottom?

The need for this rised with the implementation of the halfedge data structure where an edge object stores a prev and a next reference to another edge object. I think circular references aren't nice but lists for example also have such refenences for each next item.

Comment: This looks like a serious flaw in the design. Are these just thoughts or do you have an actual use case?

Comment: Can you be more specific and elaborate on what exactly are you trying to achieve ? The question is not very clear at least to me!

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like dependency injection(which does not cover this specific scenario, but in general such dependencies that depend themself on others etc)

Comment: @SaurabhRai The constructor for `A` requires an instance of `B`, but `B`'s constructor requires an instance of `A`.  He has circular dependencies.

Comment: Dependency Injection frameworks can automatically handle the construction, and injection of property values for you.  It's still happening, but hidden from you.  If you _really_ need this, and the objects can't be redesigned, that is the solution I would go with.

Comment: @BradleyUffner This is true, but in all the DI frameworks I have used, they really really hate circular dependencies, not just in constructor injection.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thanks for the explanation! Can't you have a parameter less constructor and a constructor with two parameters in the same class ? That may help!

Comment: @SaurabhRai Yes, that is entirely possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of assigning the edges in the constructor, do it in a separate method:

```
SomeClass a = new SomeClass();
SomeClass b = new SomeClass();
SomeClass c = new SomeClass();
a.SetEdges(b, c);
b.SetEdges(a, c);
c.SetEdges(a, b);
```

This looks much more readable. You will probably need to add some guard mechanism to prevent the class from being used before the edges are assigned; but that would also be the case if you are accepting nulls in the constructor.

Comment: ...and as a side note: if you care about code readability, `first` and especially `snd` are not good property names. Something like `FirstEdge` and `SecondEdge` reads better.

Comment: thank you. That look much more uniform. @Konnamiman I thought i could make it more generic if i use dummy names.  Thank you for all your advices!

Answer (score 2):

This is just a first idea, but I think the main approach should be to decouple the class creation from defining their relationships.

Maybe something like this would work (not sure about your exact relationships):

```
void Connect(SomeClass a, SomeClass b) {
    a.first = b;
    b.snd = a;
}
```

And use it like:

```
SomeClass a = new SomeClass();
SomeClass b = new SomeClass();
SomeClass c = new SomeClass();

Connect(a, b);
Connect(a, c);
Connect(c, b);
```

(That design is still not perfect, but at least makes it clear what happens IMHO)

Comment: You could wrap this all up in a factory to make sure that these items are always created in the correct order, with dependencies supplied.

Comment: True. Although I might need to know a bit more about the actual use case to suggest something really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to realise this as it is a circular dependency.

- You need a car to go to work (Someclass a = new Someclass(b))
- You need money to buy a car (Someclass b = new Someclass(c))
- You need to work to get money (Someclass c = new Someclass(a))

This cannot fit, you have to replace one item with something else. Go by foot, that requires no money!

Same problem with swapping values of 2 variables:

```
var a = 5;
var b = 2;
var tempvar = a;
a = b;
b = tempvar;
```

You have to get rid of the depencies or bind them after initialization. This is a logical problem, no programming problem.